# Can anyone advice me some HistoryManager( to use with AJAX ) to use with MooTools that will handle browser back and forward buttons?

Tags: javascript, ajax, mootools, browser-state

I've tried to use http://digitarald.de/project/history-manager/ but whether it doesn't work with mootools 1.2 whether i'm writing wrong code :(

Comment: It clearly states that HistoryManager works with 1.11 only.

Comment: having said that, i think harald mentioned he was working on a new ver on IRC... in the meanwhile - http://mootools.net/forge/p/historymanager

Answer (score 1):

The onhashchange.js script is a Mootools JavaScript script which fully emulates the HTML5 javascript window.onhashchange event listener. And it works well with 1.2

http://www.yearofmoo.com/onhashchange/